# Conditionally render twig variable with fallback

Tags: twig, timber

Is it possible to attempt to render a variable and use a fallback if it's falsy?

I've tried the following with no luck:

`<img src="{{ fields.icon.url || post.thumbnail.src }}" />`

`<img src="{{ fields.icon.url or post.thumbnail.src }}" />`

Comment: In the meantime, I'm using this:

`{% set icon = fields.icon.url is not empty ? fields.icon.url : post.thumbnail.src %}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `or` will cause the resulting output to become a boolean value `1` or `0`.

Instead you can use the [`default`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/default.html) filter

> The `default` filter returns the passed default value if the value is
> `undefined` or `empty`, otherwise the value of the variable:

### Example https://twigfiddle.com/hsniy6/2

```
<img src="{{ fields.icon.url|default(post.thumbnail.src) }}" />
```

---

Alternatively you can also use the [ternary operators `?:`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/templates.html#other-operators) or the null coalescing `??` operator.

The ternary operator `?:` is the equivalent to `is not empty`.
The null coalescing operator will only work when the leading variable is `undefined`, `null` and is the equivalent to `is same as(null)`.

```
<img src="{{ fields.icon.url ?: post.thumbnail.src }}" />
<img src="{{ fields.icon.url ?? post.thumbnail.src }}" />
```